# In Linux how do I retrieve the pid of the process making a system call

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm trying to understand how system call works in Linux kernel. One question I have is, how can I retrieve the pid of the process making a system call?

e.g. I'm looking at `read()` call (sync read) which I think is defined in **fs/read_write.c** as

```
ssize_t do_sync_read(struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *ppos)
```

Comment: I'd think `getpid()` would work, considering it's still the same process...?

Comment: @cHao No reason to call getpid(), when a context switch happens the current pointer gets changed (per core) to the value of the current running context which in the case of a system call is the context of the process that called it. You can check this to get the pid.

Comment: humm..not sure if getpid() works in kernel mode. I'll check that will update later. Thx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the system call context (which is the context of the calling process) you can check the global variable `current` which is of type `struct task_struct` this containts a `pid` field you can get the pid from.

Just do `current->pid` to get the pid of the current task context you are in.

I'm assuming you mean the actual code for the system call defined in the kernel.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about the "current". Will check if that works and will update later. Thx for quick response :)

Comment: <nitpick>s/In the system call context/When you make a system call, you are in a context known as process context (known as user context in older days), since the kernel is executing on behalf of a process. In process context/

Comment: @ninjalj Yeah I should have worded that differently since the main distinctions are made between kernel and process context.